# Almost same code, different output. What is JavaScript doing differently here?

Tags: javascript

First Code!

```js
x = 6;

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var list = document.createElement("li");
  var apple = document.getElementById("our-list");

  list.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Something " + x++));
  apple.appendChild(list);
});
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="btn">Click</button>

  <ul id="our-list">
    <li>Something 1</li>
    <li>Something 2</li>
    <li>Something 3</li>
    <li>Something 4</li>
    <li>Something 5</li>
  </ul>

  <script src="./javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Test Code! (Yes, I know it looks disgusting but its only for understanding and testing purpose.)

```js
var x = 6;

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("our-list").appendChild(document.createElement("li").appendChild(document.createTextNode("Something " + x++)));
});
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="btn">Click</button>

  <ul id="our-list">
    <li>Something 1</li>
    <li>Something 2</li>
    <li>Something 3</li>
    <li>Something 4</li>
    <li>Something 5</li>
  </ul>

  <script src="./javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Why is this not creating a list element? It seems like its entirely skipping the `document.createElement("li")` and appending a TextNode straight away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, in your second code, you are appending the return value of

```
document.createElement("li").appendChild(document.createTextNode("Something " + x++))
```

to the `document.getElementById("our-list")`.

If you look at the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) of `appendChild`, this method returns the appended child node. Therefore, when you do

```
document.createElement("li")
.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Something " + x++))
```

what you are appending to the **our-list** is not the newly created **li** element, but the child note which you intended to be inside that **li** node.

Comment: So, in one line (without the use of assigning variables) how would I force JavaScript to return an element that has a text value instead of only returning the text value?

Comment: @JeremyJeminMunshi: See Rajkumar's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52982394/4012073

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to do the same in one line without using variables. Hope this will help you.

```
document.getElementById("our-list").appendChild(document.createElement("li")).appendChild(document.createTextNode("Something " + x++));
```